# How to find direction points using Google Maps API 3?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, maproute

I am drawing a route in Google Maps. I have passed the start point, way points and end points. My route is drawing correctly. I am using Google Maps API 3.

```
request = {
  origin: originAddress,
  destination: destinationAddress,
  waypoints: waypoints,
  optimizeWaypoints: false,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
}
```

If I change the route direction, then how to find the changed direction points' latitude and longitude?

[image]

Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [not able to comment so posting as answer]
http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/draggable-directions/saving-draggable-directions-saving-waypoints-google-directions-google-maps-v3.htm